# I want to click a link in the browser without having to open

Tags: html, dom, hyperlink, browser-extension

I want to write a code (in any language or console of browsers or creating an extension to browsers) to open a link or all links on a website in the same browser (Chrome or Firefox or other) without having to click or using keyboard. 
Simpler: Each site has several links, I want open one of these links without clicking that execute with mouse click event. 
Can everyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

try this browser extension if you are using chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=no

Comment: Thanks @Patric, but I don't know this opens links directive or referral. Do you know?